# How to call a method from another class

Tags: java, methods

Hello I am new to object oriented programming. Normally I'll call a method by using a constructor. But in this case it doesn´t seem to work. 
I want to call method getCommands() from the CommandWords class to the Game class. Could anyone please help me to understand how I can achieve this? Thanks

```
public class Game() {
    private void printHelp() 
    {
    System.out.println("You are " + currentRoom.getDescription());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Your command words are:");
    System.out.println("   go quit help");
    //getCommands();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Your exits are: ");
    if(currentRoom.northExit != null) {
        System.out.print("north ");
    }
    if(currentRoom.eastExit != null) {
        System.out.print("east ");
    }
    if(currentRoom.southExit != null) {
        System.out.print("south ");
    }
    if(currentRoom.westExit != null) {
        System.out.print("west ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Class from which I want to call method getCommands()

```
public class CommandWords
{
// a constant array that holds all valid command words
private static final String[] validCommands = {
    "go", "quit", "help"
};

//Method which gets the String representation of valid commands
public String getCommands() {
    String printer= "";
    for (int i=0; i<validCommands.length; i++) {
        printer = printer + validCommands[i] + ", ";
    }
    return printer;
}

/**
 * Constructor - initialise the command words.
 */
public CommandWords()
{
    // nothing to do at the moment...
}
```

}

Comment: If you change `getCommands()` to be a `static` method, then you can invoke it by doing something like this:  `String cmds=CommandWords.getCommands();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new object instance and call method via that instance.

```
CommandWords commandWords = new CommandWords();
String commands = commandWords.getCommands();
System.out.println(commands);
```

Replace above line with **//getCommands();**

Answer (score 0):

You don't "call methods" with constructors.  You need to create an instance of your CommandWords class, then call the method on it:

```
public class Game() {
    private void printHelp() 
    {
    System.out.println("You are " + currentRoom.getDescription());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Your command words are:");
    System.out.println("   go quit help");
    CommandWords words = new CommandWords();
    String results = words.getCommands();
```

Have you read the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
---
-------
System.out.println("Your command words are:");
System.out.println("   go quit help");
CommandWords commandWords = new CommandWords();
String s1 =commandWords.getCommands();
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Your exits are: ");
-------
---
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything with the constructor. Just create an instance of CommandWords class and call getcommands method.

```
private void printHelp() 
{
System.out.println("You are " + currentRoom.getDescription());
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Your command words are:");
System.out.println("   go quit help");
CommandWords command_words=new CommandWords();
command_words.getCommands();
System.out.println();
```